# Instantiate and Destroy a Prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i need a help. I created a script that spawn a simple gameObject at the mouse position. This gameObject is a prefab. Since i need it to move and then destroy once it is out of the screen, this is the script i created:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class foodManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject food;
    

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }
    void Update()
    {

        Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;

        Vector2 objPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

        food.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, -3);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
           food = Instantiate(food, objPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        }

        if (food.transform.position.y < -5f)
        {
            Destroy(food);
        }

    }
}
```

Once i start the game, i can't instantiate the prefab. I only can if the prefab is already in the scene, and once it gets destroyed, i cant anymore.
Can you guys help me if you understand where's the problem? Thanks in advice!

Comment: You dont need `as GameObject`. food will be GameObject in any case

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are replacing the food prefab in your script. So it will only be able to be instantiated once. Seperate that into two different variables.

```
public class foodManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject foodPrefab;
    public Transform food;
    
    void Update()
    {
        HandleSpawning();
        HandleDestroyingFood();
    }
    
    void HandleSpawning()
    {
        // Only allow one Food to be instantiated at a time.
        if (food != null) return;
        
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            Vector2 objPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
            GameObject newFood = Instantiate(food, objPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            food = newFood.transform;
        }
    }
    
    void HandleDestroyingFood()
    {
        if (food.position.y < -5f)
        {
            Destroy(food.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the `as GameObject` is redundant.`Instantiate` is generic and returns whatever type the prefab is of

Comment: this doesnt work, idk why. If i remove the prefab from the scene, i still cant spawn any food. Plus, it says that i cant destroy directly the transform (in this case, the transform called food). Any idea?

Comment: @LeonardoBiagi ah sorry. Try: `Destroy(food.gameObject);`. When destroying something you must destroy the gameObject not the transform. My bad

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
       food = Instantiate(food, objPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }
```

this Line is the main problem as you are overwriting the prefab with a new Instantiated object

In the starting, you are using the **food** variable to be the prefab and after the Instantiate, you overwrite it with the new game object which is not the **prefab**

`public GameObject food;` I'm assuming this line is for the Prefab you drag in the editor

So, to solve this Make a **new variable** to hold the Instantiated Object.
Not the **food** variable you use  for the Prefab.